# Освобождаем процесс после отправки файла?

Tags: c#

Пишу программу на C#, консольное приложение. Вообщем есть файл, который я прицепляю к письму, письмо отправляю программно, все отправляется, все хорошо, но после удаляю его:
System.IO.File.Delete(filename); и в итоге ошибка, что этот файл занят каким то процессом. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Кара небесная

Comment: не понял?!

Comment: я вот не понял, причем здесь c#

а также email, файл, процесс и удалить

Спасибо.

Comment: так понятнее?

Comment: >Наши телепаты допрашивают оракулов, чтобы узнать откуда у них сведения которые они распространяют

>все отправляется, все хорошо
если бы это было правдой, мы бы об этом не знали

Ваш код представляет собой тайну какого-либо рода?

Я интересуюсь потому, что хотел бы попросить его предоставить.

Comment: я думаю остальная часть кода не значительная...

Comment: я думаю проблема в этой строке

    SendEmail();

Comment: а сейчас??

Answer (score 2):

После отправки письма скорее всего нужно сделать

```
attachmentFile.Dispose()
```

чтобы файл отпустило пожалуйста.

Поскольку Attachment реализиует IDisposable, то тут можно и using (attachmentFile) { } навернуть

Comment: про  using (attachmentFile) { } не совсем понял вас

Comment: Вы обратили внимание на несущественную часть ответа.

Пользуясь случаем, спешу посоветовать http://www.apress.com/9781430242338 - на (почти) всех трекерах страны!

Comment: Короче не помогает attachmentFile.Dispose();
просто консолька висит и все, вроде бы должна выполнить и закрыться,а  она висит...еще вопрос, хотел чтобы консолька была скрыта.

Comment: Поведение программы изменилсоь после добавления attachmentFile.Dispose() ?

Comment: Ошибка вылазит: В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и ожидания

Comment: К сожалению, наступили выходные и праздники и телепаты улетели на юг.

Поэтому, раз сообщение об ошибке изменилось, не могли бы вы указать строку, на которой эта самая ошибка появляется?

Comment: :-D дак как раз на этой самой attachmentFile.Dispose();

Comment: Оно компилируется или нет?

Comment: `+1` за "отпустило пожалуйста" `:)`